# Why boost asio async_read_some does not invoke the callback in a certain situation?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm implementing a serial communication protocol to communicate with a external device over UART. I'm using boost asio for this. So far everything works fine, except very little cases. I found that it is possible that the reading from the socket does *"miss"* 1 byte in some cases.

I checked the serial communication by using a UART sniffer to see the raw data which comes and goes over the socket. This being sad, I did see the full frame of bytes being transmitted over the socket. But in my application the last byte was just not received.

I found that his byte is not *"lost"* it's somehow just *"stuck"* in the kernel buffer or something. Because on receiving the next frame I do get this *"missing"* byte in front of all the new bytes. This would not be a big problem if the frames would come in continuously. But the next frame is only sent by the device if the previous frame was acknowledged by the program.

Here is the code of my write and handle receive method:

```
void serial::write(std::vector<uint8_t> message) {
    static boost::mutex mu;
    mu.lock();
    uint8_t cmd = message.at(3);
    //if its an ACK frame - just send it
    if ((message[3]>>4)==0xE) {
        // --- Write message to serial port --- //
        boost::asio::write(serial_,boost::asio::buffer(message));
        usleep(20000);
        mu.unlock();
        return;
    }
    //if its not an ACK frame write the frame and wait for an ACK!
    //create new promise for the request
    promise = new boost::promise<deque<uint8_t>>;
    boost::unique_future<deque<uint8_t>> future = promise->get_future();
    // --- Write message to serial port --- //
    boost::asio::write(serial_,boost::asio::buffer(message));
    usleep(20000);
    mu.unlock();
    //wait for ACK or timeout
    if     (future.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100))==boost::future_status::timeout) {
        spdlog::get("logger")->trace("ACK timeout!");
        //delete pointer and set it to 0
        delete promise;
        promise=nullptr;
        //need to resend this frame
    }
    //delete pointer and set it to 0 after getting a message
    delete promise;
    promise=nullptr;
}
```

handle receive:

```
void serial::handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
     static deque<uint8_t> read_buffer;
     static boost::posix_time::ptime start =    boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time( );
    if (boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time( ) - start > boost::posix_time::milliseconds(99)  && !read_buffer.empty()) {
        spdlog::get("logger")->trace("time condition, clearing buffer!");
        read_buffer.clear();
    }
    start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time( );
    if (!error) {
        //push all the recieved data into the deque
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes_transferred; i++) {
            read_buffer.push_back((int)data_[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (error){
    spdlog::get("logger")->error("\n\n\n\nERROR: {0}\n\n\n\n", error);
    }
    while ( !read_buffer.empty()) {
        /*do here some checks if this could be a correct frame
       ...
       ...
       ...
       */
        //received frame is ready
        //check if it is an ACK frame
        //check if its a data frame and ACK it!
        //send an ACK if its a dataframe
        if (ACK)) {
            write(frame);
        }
        //give the data to the upper layer                  
        m_Receive_data_handler(receivedFrame,receivedFrame.size());
        }
    serial_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_,max_length),
                        boost::bind(&serial::handle_receive, this,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}
```

Maybe somebody has an idea why it works on most cases, but fails just with the last byte of the frame?

Thanks!

Comment: Building with [`BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) defined may help provide some insight into the handlers.  Also, in  `serial::handle_receive()`, what happens in the `while (!read_buffer.empty())` loop if a complete frame has not been read?

Comment: Oh, sorry! In this while it performs the validation check and gives the frame to the upper layer until it's empty. It could be possible that there are more than one valid frame in the buffer.

Comment: But what occurs if a complete frame has **not** been read?  Does it loop indefinitely?

Comment: No, there are breaking conditions further down in the loop. Sorry I removed it in order to make it more short.

Comment: With the default serial options used by Boost.Asio, if any data is available, an outstanding `async_read_some()` operation _should_ complete (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268150/1053968) to query how many bytes are available).  Showing the output of handler tracking, serial port initialization/configuration, and the code flow may illuminate the problem.   There is no need to show lower details (e.g. how to verify if the buffer contains a frame), but showing flow is helpful (e.g. when there is no frame, break out of loop).

Comment: Hey p0fi, did you find a solution to this?  I'm also seeing something similar on a Linux project I'm working on.  I suspect it's something on the Linux side rather than Boost.  Like if you give async_read_some a 1 byte buffer it still doesn't call it's callback.  Currently looking at ioctl's and the options on the native serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an asynchronous call to read data, and there's no guarantee that you'll read everything.

If you check the documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html

> Remarks
>
> The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes.
>   Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.

What happens probably is that in your case your kernel has little buffers, and it signals the application when it has some data, but you are trying to send more data than that. Once it is stuck with only little data left in the buffers, it'll wait for more data to come and save a call. These are just assumptions though, I don't have first hand experience with UART.

Would switching to a synchronous read call (read_some) be an option?

Comment: I know that there is no guarantee to receive all the desired data at once, to cover this I implemented a mechanism to build up the frame ever time a new call of the handle receive is done. So this isn't the problem. The problem is really only that the handle receive isn't called with this last byte in the buffers. But it is called sometimes with only 1 byte in the buffer. So I don't think that the number of bytes in the buffer is the reason. I often saw handle receive calls with 1 byte of data.
A synchronous read call is no option i think.

Comment: then it sounds like a classical indexing problem, maybe somewhere you start counting from 0, and the number of bytes transferred is not zero-indexed? I'm thinking of the call to handle_receive, in the extra code that you added to handle the frames, probably you don't call it back with the right number of read bytes.

Comment: If the number of bytes transferred would be wrong, it wouldn't be working in any case i think?

Comment: not if you tell your application that you have received one less byte, then the next time you pick up from there and you have the remaining one. If I were you I'd add logging to all the different sizes that you pass along the different function.

Comment: at the end of my handle receive I invoke a new read_some, just with a placeholder (which i don't quite get actually, what does this mean?) so the bytes_received is calculated not by me I think. Where would you suggest to add logging?

Comment: I have a log like this, which seems valid, it says it was called with 2 bytes read and exactly 2 got added.

```----------handle receive call -----------with 2 bytes -------------

[12:16:36:627473]  [trace] BUFFER before READ: 50 00 23 a0 01 00 1b 80 11 00 01 03 7a 20 a3 00 01 00 0a 21 63 02 e3 00 00 ff ff ff 21 63 02 e4 00 00 a5 00 

[12:16:36:627762]  [trace] BUFFER after READ: 50 00 23 a0 01 00 1b 80 11 00 01 03 7a 20 a3 00 01 00 0a 21 63 02 e3 00 00 ff ff ff 21 63 02 e4 00 00 a5 00 4f 29 
```

Comment: In general, asynchronous operations use the exact same system calls as synchronous operations to perform the underlying I/O, so using `read_some()` will likely yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that, rather than stuck in a kernel buffer somewhere, the last byte is stuck in the UART's receive FIFO?  Perhaps you need to configure the driver with an inter-character timeout?

Comment: Hm, how would I do that?

Comment: That depends on the underlying serial driver implementation, OS, platform, etc.  If you're using the boost::asio serial port class then in principle it takes care of setting these things up for you, but you never know...